# Sync Audio (MediaPlayer) with Animation.setStartOffset

Tags: android, android-animation, android-mediaplayer

I am using setStartOffset to delay animation start. Delay or offset is different for different ImageViews. Animation has listener register to detect it's end. I thought that onAnimationStart will kick when animation really starts but it is informed immediately (without consideration for offset). I was looking to introduce delay to mediaplayer but did not find anything like that. I looked also at SoundPool but could not see a solution there either.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use postDelayed to call start on the MediaPlayer and animation at the same time.